# How to "reverse" array when setting values to make getting/setting more convenient?

Tags: c#

I'm using enums to make it easier to keep track of data. Because of this, I found it more convenient to access values using an array than accessing directly. Here's a sample of my class:

```
public class Data {
    // Values
    int age;
    int salary;
    int booksOwned;

    // Accessor
    int[] data { get { int[] values = {age, salary, booksOwned}; return values; }}

    // Constructor
    public Data(int x, int y, int z) { age = x; salary = y; booksOwned = z; }

    
}
```

I did the opposite before, using the array as the base and having get/sets with the value names (age { get { return data[0]}}), but ran into issues, as the values in the base object would be updated.

Anyway, this has been working fine to access data, but I'm having trouble when setting data with this method. If I try:

```
Data tempData = new Data(22, 40, 3);
tempData.data[0] = 23;
```

I (understandably) run into issues. Can I make a setter to access these values, or would I be better off just accessing the values directly?

edit to add context:
These values are just samples, but I need to be able to adjust these values easily. In the actual sample, I have 8 data types, and they are all adjusted in the same way. This is something along the lines of what I (would like to) use the enum for:

```
public bool Increase(Data data, DataTypeEnum dataTypeEnum) {
    if (data[(int)dataTypeEnum] < 100) {
        data[(int)dataTypeEnum]++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then in another area:

```
int numberToAdd = 30;
while (numberToAdd > 0) {
     DataTypeEnum dataToAddTo = (DataTypeEnum)Random.Range(0,3);
     if (Increase(tempData, dataToAddTo)) numberToAdd--;
}
```

Comment: Do you not want values in the base object to be updated? You want a clone with new values?

Comment: The base object is a scriptableObject, so it's a shared data object across multiple scripts. I want to read values from it, but not update them. For whatever reason, the values on the scriptable object are being updated when I copy and change them, so this was a workaround that I attempted.

Unfortunately, it looks like this will not work, either.

Comment: Is this about an array of structures vs. structures of arrays?

Comment: Not really, no. I was trying to find an easier way to set the values by using enums. If I use the method in the latter half of the post, it goes from ~60 lines to 5 (lots of duplication), but update the base values

Comment: I've read this question three times now and I still don't understand the point of this class or the problem you're having with it (except of course that you are attempting to access a private property and attempting to write to a read-only property; both problems have obvious solutions). Also, you allude to enums but there aren't any in your code example. Can you back up and explain what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It sounds like you want to get the values and then change them but then this also changes them in the referenced object. We need more context in the post. We don't have any idea what your code looks like.

Comment: I added some context to the post. In my actual code, the different data values are very similar, but are used in different ways, which is why I started with defined values to begin with

Comment: a) It looks like you are trying to create a data type that behaves like an array. To accomplish this use an indexer and implement `IEnumerable<int>`. b) Your `Increase()` function only acts on `Data` type so is should be a method in the class and not externally defined. c) Data should be stored in one place, not in both a field and an array because this will lead to inconsistencies and bugs.

Answer (score 3):

This is  horrible design. OOP is about **classes**, not named or index data-elements. It's way easier to understand to write `myPerson.Age` or `myPerson.Salary` than `myData[0]`, isn't it?

Furthermore every member can have it's own type. Imagine you'd need a further property like `DateOfBirth` instead of `Age`. Then you get a problem, as all your arrays elements are ints, while you need a `DateTime`.

You can even implement your own getter- and setter-functions for every member.

I'm using enums to make it easier to keep track of data. Because of this, I found it more convenient to access values using an array than accessing directly. Here's a sample of my class:

```
public class Data {
    // Values
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int BooksOwned {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to re-invent [deconstructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct):

```
//TODO: you may want to have "readonly struct" instead of "class"
public class Data {
  // Values: let's user read but not modify them
  public int Age {get;}
  public int Salary {get;}
  public int BooksOwned {get;}

  // Deconstructor:
  // Instead of array we return values
  public void Deconstruct(out int age, out int salary, out int booksOwned) {
    age = this.Age;
    salary = this.Salary;
    booksOwned = this.BooksOwned;
  }

  // Constructor (let's use readable names instead of x, y, z)
  public Data(int age, int salary, int booksOwned) { 
    //TODO: Validate input here, e.g. age must not be negative etc.
    this.Age = age;
    this.Salary = salary;
    this.BooksOwned = booksOwned; 
  }
}
```

Usage

```
Data data = new Data(1, 2, 3);

...

// ignore age - note "_",
// but declare and return mySalary and myBooksOwned
// The syntax is similar to array, but it is a tuple
// which allows you to have different types for different variables
(_, int mySalary, int myBooksOwned) = data;

Console.Write($"Salary is {mySalary}, owned {myBooksOwned}");
```